# fb hw conflict: nouveau vs VESA VGA

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, bootable, backtrack

I would like to start off by saying that I am aware that there are many similar questions, however none have an answer that has solved my problem. Anyways, here's the problem: I have an HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF running Windows 7 x64 with an inbuilt Intel processor - which has its own graphics - and I have a separate nVIDIA graphics card. I am trying to install BackTrack5 r3 via a live USB. However, when I boot into the BackTrack live USB and attempt to open the default text option, commands are executed for a few seconds before I get the following error:

fb: conflicting fb hw usage nouveau vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver

After this, the BackTrack live USB/installation is frozen. I cannot do anything, and to proceed I have to force-shutdown my computer and turn it back on. I have tried everything that I have seen on the internet, but to no avail. I have tried, along with their results:

- Passing i915.modeset=1/i915.modeset=0 - I get "Attached SCSI removable media", after which I can type, however what I enter has no effect
- Passing nomodeset - Has no effect
- Disabling KMS/passing nouveau.modeset=0 - Has no effect
- Uninstalling nouveau driver/blacklisting nouveau driver/startx - Can't get to that point
- Anything else that involves Terminal or commands - Again, can't get to that point
- Reinstalling nVIDIA drivers from their website - Installs the same as any other nVIDIA driver with no additional options, makes no difference
- Formatting the live USB and installing it again (with different builds) - Makes no difference
- Disabling Intel graphics through BIOS - BIOS is password-protected with a password I don't know (planning to reset BIOS/CMOS password through motherboard soon)
- Using a non-deprecated/still-supported OS similar to BackTrack - I don't want an OS like BackTrack, I want BackTrack itself and nothing else

I have no other Linux operating system installed on my computer. I am otherwise fully prepared for a dual-boot. Below are my system specs:

Motherboard: HP 611834-001
CPU: Intel i5-2400 @ 3.1 GHz
RAM: 8GB
GPU: GeForce GTX 750 Ti 2GB

I would hate to have to remove/disable my external graphics card for BackTrack to work, so any solutions that don't require that would be thoroughly appreciated. If I could remove this driver that's causing problems in Windows, even if it means disabling inbuilt Intel graphics, that would be optimal. I apologize for the wall of text, and thank you in advance for your help.